# Please suggest necessary setting for better sharp image with telephoto lens 70 -300mm VRF4.5-6.3? Nikon D5300

Tags: nikon, teleconverter

Does the teleconverter support  for sharp image specially for birding?
Please suggest

Comment: The title and the body seem to be asking different questions. Could you edit the body to be self-contained without the title and to make it clear what your actual question is?

Comment: It is not only about settings. It is about using proper technique, including the settings you select, as well as other important things.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm your lens is f4.5 -6.3 aperture so to get a sharp image your shutter speed should not be less than 1/300th of a second if hand held ( rule of thumb no less than max focal length of your lens ) 
For a more controlled shot use a tripod gorillapod or a bean bag for lenses, or a monopod all these things can help.